# OnSubmit and OnChange in multer file upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, multer, gridfs

I want to upload two objects(file and literal) with one action.
Here's the defined states, toggle, onSubmit, onChangeFile and onChangeText functions(SliderModal.js)

```
const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [fileData, setFileData] = useState([]);
  const [slideData, setSlideData] = useState({
    caption: ''
  })


  const toggle = () => {
    setModal(!modal);
  };

  const onChangeFile = e => {
    setFileData(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const onChangeText = e => {
    setSlideData({
      ...slideData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newFile = new FormData();
    newFile.append('file', fileData);

    const { caption } = slideData;

    const newSlide = {
      caption
    }

    // Add file via addItem action
    addFile(newSlide);
    addFile(newFile);

    // Close modal
    toggle();
  }
```

and my route post method(files.js):

```
router.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {

  const newFile = new File({
    fileID: req.file.id,
    src: 'api/files/image/' + req.file.filename,
    altText: 'No image',
    caption: req.body.caption
  })
  newFile.save()
});
```

When I try to send this with this functions I get error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
[0]     at router.post (/home/wiktor/CarouselProject/routes/api/files.js:76:22)
[0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/wiktor/CarouselProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[0]     at next (/home/wiktor/CarouselProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
[0]     at multerMiddleware (/home/wiktor/CarouselProject/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:18:41)
[0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/wiktor/CarouselProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[0]     at next (/home/wiktor/CarouselProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
[0]     at Route.dispatch (/home/wiktor/CarouselProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
[0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/wiktor/CarouselProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[0]     at /home/wiktor/CarouselProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
[0]     at Function.process_params (/home/wiktor/CarouselProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
[0]     at next (/home/wiktor/CarouselProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
[0]     at Function.handle (/home/wiktor/CarouselProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
[0]     at router (/home/wiktor/CarouselProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
[0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/wiktor/CarouselProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[0]     at trim_prefix (/home/wiktor/CarouselProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
[0]     at /home/wiktor/CarouselProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
```

This

> [0]     at router.post
>   (/home/wiktor/CarouselProject/routes/api/files.js:76:22)

is the error in this POST route method. Exactly here:

> fileID: req.file.id

When I get rid of this I get eqiuvalent error, but this time with:

> req.file.filename

However I get all the data on database, except

> caption

When I get rid of all req.file properties in route method I get even two files literal. So the

> addFile(newSlide)
>   didn't work, however I know that I should do it with one addFile, but I don't know how.

At this time there's only one method that works.

```
   <form className="uploadForm" action="/api/files" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label className="control-label">Select File</label>
            <input name="caption" id="input-1" type="text" className="caption" />
            <input name="file" id="input-1" type="file" className="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   </form> ,
```

but it didn't use onSubmit and onChange functions. And I really want to do it with those functions.
How to achieve that?

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, long time ago.  I'll write it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new `FormData()` and append all the parts. Here's the answer:

```
 const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newSlide = new FormData();
    newSlide.append('slide', imageData);

    const { header, caption } = slideData;
    newSlide.append('caption', caption);
    newSlide.append('header', header);

    addSlide(newSlide);

    setImageData(null);

    // Close modal
    toggle();
  }
```

Eventually, if you have many text fields you can use (after appending `slide` from `imageData`):

```
 Object.keys(slideData).map( key => newSlide.append(key,slideData[key]));
```